# I understand this is a Poisson distribution, but I am struggling on actually applying the information.

Tags: statistics, poisson-distribution

Given an arrival process with an average of one per unit of time, what is the probability that an arrival occurs in the first 2 time units?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X \sim \text{Poisson}(1)$. Then we have that $\mathbb{P}(X=x) = \frac{e^{-1}}{x!}$. Can you see how to compute the answer?

Comment: Might need to walk me through this a bit more. The average, and therefore expected outcome is 1unit/one unit of time. Therefore, lambda is = 1. What is x equal to? .5 because it's one unit / 2 units of time?

Comment: Doesn't that comute to .36? How does that make sense. If we average 1 per unit, then shouldn't it be a high probability that we have one in 2 units?

Comment: Are you sure this is a Poisson process? This feels like a continuous distribution may work better.

Comment: I'm pretty sure....how would you do it via continuous distribution?

Comment: Poisson process is fine. ***Hint*** (to both): The probability that exactly $n$ arrivals occur within the first two time units is $\frac{2^n}{n!}e^{-2}$ . ***Question*** (to @coder7155). Are you asking for the probability of exactly one arrival or at least one arrival ?

Comment: the question states "an arrival" so I think it means at least one

Comment: does this mean I can do exactly 0 arrivals usuing your formula and then do 1-that?

Comment: The formula also works for $n=0$. $2^0=1$ and $0!=1$. The probability to have zero arrivals is therefore $e^{-2}\approx 13.5\%$,  exactly one arrival is $2e^{-2}\approx 27.1\%$ and at least one arrival $1-e^{-2}\approx 86.5\%$.

Comment: Makes sense @KurtG. ! Now, the question is :
. Show that, if 4 minutes have already elapsed, the probability that a further 4 minutes will elapse 
before the next occurrence is exp(-4λ). Explain your answer in words. 

How do I show this? I assume this means they are statistically interdependent but how do I show?

Comment: Hint: In the previous comment I effectively wrote that the probability that a further two minutes will elapse before the next occurrence happens is $e^{-t\lambda}$. That was with $t=2$ and $\lambda=1$. I am expecting you to apply this to the new question.